# Customising object blocks in CKEditor4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to customise the styles in the latest CK Editor 4 using the code below in the config.js. All off the inline/block styles show up fine however the object styles don't show.

I tried the example code on the CK Editor [site example](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.stylesSet) and again inline/block showed up but not the object styles.

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    { name: 'message', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'message' } },
    { name: 'boxout', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'boxout' } },
    { name: 'clear', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'clear' } },
    { name: 'button', element: 'a', attributes: { 'class': 'inline-button' } },
    { name: 'leftcolumn', element: 'ul', attributes: {'class': 'list-left'}},
    { name: 'rightcolumn', element: 'ul', attributes: {'class': 'list-right'} },
    { name: 'imageright', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'image-right'} },
   { name: 'imageleft', element: 'img', attributes: {'class': 'image-left'} }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object styles will only appear if it applies to the currently selected/highlighted element.

For example, the `button` style should appear in the drop down if you select an `a` tag in the editor window while the `imageright` and `imageleft` styles will appear if to select an `img` tag.